# Maxima: define a function that returns a random integer in a range, such that the value is distinct from another value or a list of other values

Tags: arrays, function, numbers, maxima

**N.B.** *the question in the title is addressed in the "Edit: Larger Problem" section, below*

---

Is there a function that will return the type of a variable, in Maxima?

I'm not sure if `type` is the correct word (I'm very new to this but get the impression it may have a specific technical sense), what I'm looking for is a function that can return `true` or `false` if a variable `x` is a number or an array, e.g. if x : 6;

```
IsArray(x) = false
IsNumber(x) = true
```

or, e.g. if `y : [1,2,3]`;

```
IsArray(y) = true;
IsNumber(y) = false;
```

I've tried searching the Maxima documentation but haven't been able to find anything. Any help would be appreciated.

---

**Edit: Larger Problem.**

I wrote a function that will return a random value `y` from a range, while ensuring that `y` is distinct from another value `b`:

```
DistinctValue(x,y,LowerLim,UpperLim):= block(
                  [newY:y], 
                  if x = newY 
                  then newY:DistinctValue(x,rand_range(LowerLim,UpperLim),LowerLim,UpperLim) 
                  else newY:y, return(newY));
```

where `rand_range(LowerLim,UpperLim)` is another custom function that chooses a random integer `LowerLim` ≤ x ≤ `UpperLim`.

It didn't take long for me to realize that sometimes I will need several such distinct values, so I tweaked the above code so that it can take an array as argument:

```
DistinctValue(x,y,LowerLim,UpperLim):= block([newY:y], 
    for i:1 thru length(x)
    do  if x[i] = newY
         then newY:DistinctValue(x,rand_range(LowerLim,UpperLim),LowerLim,UpperLim), 
    return(newY));
```

While I know the latter can be used for cases where there is a single number to exclude from the range, simply by placing it in square brackets, I was hoping to learn to write a function that could take `x` as *either* a number *or* an array. I figured the easiest way to do this would be to use an if / else statement that evaluated the type of variable `x` is, e.g.

```
DistinctValue(x,y,LowerLim,UpperLim):= block([newY:y], 
/* if it's a list, run the list version of the function */
 if IsList(x) 
 then
    for i:1 thru length(x)
    do  if x[i] = newY
         then  newY : DistinctValue(x, rand_range(LowerLim,UpperLim), LowerLim, UpperLim)
/* otherwise run the number version of the function */
 else  
      if x = newY 
      then newY : DistinctValue(x, rand_range(LowerLim,UpperLim), LowerLim,UpperLim) 
      else newY:y,, 
    return(newY));
```

**While this may seem superfluous, we're implementing Maxima in another, fairly complicated environment, and it'll be used by folks who have  even less experience than I. Moreover, I expect to encounter other cases where it will be more of a necessity, than an option, in the near future.**

Comment: There isn't a catch-all for all possible types of expressions, but there are some specific predicates: `numberp` for literal numbers, `listp` for lists, and others (`integerp` for literal integers, `floatnump` for floats, maybe `matrixp` for matrices, maybe others, I don't remember for sure without looking). By the way, in Maxima, `[1, 2, 3]` is a list, not an array. Maybe you can say more about the larger problem you want to solve.

Comment: @RobertDodier thank you for taking the time to read and reply. I admit to being very unclear as to the difference between lists, arrays and matrices, in Maxima. I have no programming background and find the documentation extremely opaque. I've added the larger context, and will see if any of the options you suggested do the trick; however, if you have any advice, I'd greatly appreciate it -- I'm in fully way over my head :)

Comment: Rax, no problem about lacking experience with programming. For problems which benefit from discussion, probably the Maxima mailing list is the best forum. See: https://sourceforge.net/projects/maxima/lists/maxima-discuss You mention that you're building a larger system others will use. If it has anything to do with educational purposes, some work along those lines exists already. I'm aware of a project called STACK headed by Chris Sangwin and also I think maybe there is a Moodle plug-in for Maxima. I don''t really know more about either of those projects.

Comment: @RobertDodier Really appreciate the friendly tone: getting started is rather intimidating. Thank you for pointing me to those additional resources, I'll be sure to look into them and forward them to our chief programmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the function DistinctValue, here's how I would implement a function which returns a random value from a range which is distinct from a single value or from all of a list of values.

```
DistinctValue(x, LowerLim, UpperLim) :=
    if listp(x)
        then block([y: rand_range(LowerLim, UpperLim)],
                    if member(y, x) /* need to try again */
                        then DistinctValue(x, LowerLim, UpperLim)
                        else y)
        else DistinctValue([x], LowerLim, UpperLim);
```

This is somewhat different from what's shown above; that might mean I've misunderstood the requirements. I'll let you be the judge of that.

`rand_range` can be expressed as just

```
rand_range(LowerLim, UpperLim) := LowerLim + random(UpperLim - LowerLim + 1);
```

The `UpperLim - LowerLim + 1` assures that `UpperLim` can be returned, otherwise the maximum random value from `rand_range` is `UpperLim` minus 1, assuming `LowerLim` and `UpperLim` are integers.

EDIT: Seems to work -- here I've already `load(descriptive);` to get `discrete_freq`.

```
(%i32) makelist (DistinctValue ([13, 15, 17], 12, 18), 100);
(%o32) [18, 18, 14, 16, 18, 16, 12, 12, 18, 18, 12, 14, 12, 12, 
18, 18, 14, 12, 12, 14, 16, 18, 12, 16, 12, 16, 14, 18, 16, 12, 
14, 16, 14, 16, 16, 12, 14, 18, 14, 14, 14, 12, 16, 18, 14, 18, 
18, 14, 14, 18, 12, 16, 18, 12, 16, 16, 12, 14, 16, 18, 16, 14, 
16, 12, 16, 12, 14, 18, 16, 14, 12, 18, 14, 12, 16, 18, 12, 12, 
14, 14, 18, 16, 18, 14, 14, 18, 16, 14, 12, 12, 14, 12, 18, 18, 
12, 18, 12, 18, 18, 18]
(%i33) discrete_freq (%);
(%o33)        [[12, 14, 16, 18], [26, 25, 21, 28]]
```

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you _so_ much for taking the time to read and reply. There are a few things that are new to me, here, so I'll need a bit of time to work through it, to confirm it has the intended functionality, but I've up-voted the answer for now, and will mark it as correct as soon as I've had a chance to confirm. Again, really appreciate your time and insight, thank you!

Comment: Finally, your explanation is so clear that it was simple to follow and verify. I think it was just the `load(descriptive);` and `discrete_freq` functions that made me nervous (& and I _do_ still need to look into them). Appreciate the other minor improvements, throughout.